# log4j2.properties daily rollover doesn't work

Tags: elasticsearch, logging, log4j2

I want to change log4j2 configuration of ElasticSearch in the following way. Logs from ElasticSearch should be saved in directories: `/path/to/log/{year}/{month}/{day}/cluster_name.log` but TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy makes rollover only after end of the day. I've been trying to use TimeBasedRollingPolicy but it can't be configured through *.properties file. I rewrited whole log4j2.properties to log4j2.xml file but ElasticSearch requires log4j2.properites. At the end I decided to resign from logging letter-day's logs to appropriate directory. I returned to TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy and I used this filePattern `/path/to/log/%d{yyyy/MM/dd}/cluster_name.log` but still doesn't work.

Larger part of config file:

```
appender.rolling.type = RollingFile
appender.rolling.name = rolling
appender.rolling.fileName = /path/to/log/cluster_name.log
appender.rolling.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.rolling.layout.pattern = [%d{ISO8601}][%-5p][%-25c{1.}] %marker%.-10000m%n
appender.rolling.filePattern = /path/to/log/%d{yyyy/MM/dd}/cluster_name.log
appender.rolling.policies.type = Policies
appender.rolling.policies.time.type = TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.rolling.policies.time.interval = 1
appender.rolling.policies.time.modulate = true
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `%d{yyyy/MM/dd}` pattern will create directory having name like `2017/09/19` which is invalid directory name. That is why, it is not working.

Try below `filePattern` -

```
appender.rolling.filePattern = /path/to/log/$${date:yyyy}/$${date:MM}/$${date:dd}/cluster_name_%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log
```

It will rotate log files like below -

> /path/to/log/{year}/{month}/{day}/cluster_name_{date}.log

Giving date in file name is mandatory. Without this, it may not work.

Comment: Still doesn't create any directory.